# Calling import in application.rb causes rake tasks to fail in a jruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, jruby

I created a [simple app](https://github.com/dalton/java_system) to demonstrate my issue.

In this system, I updated the application.rb to allow me to update System properties by adding the lines

```
require 'java'
include Java
import Java::JavaLang::System
```

This has no impact when running typical rails tasks like rails server or rails console, but rake tasks fail.

```
rake java_system:test
```

results in

```
rake aborted!
can't convert Class into String
```

Any ideas on how to get rake working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple solution.  Apparently rake [defines its own import method](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb) which messes with import in jruby.  Calling java_import instead fixes the issue!

[source](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-3171?focusedCommentId=160043&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-160043)